# Blackberry QNX Emulator

Tags: android, blackberry, emulation

Is there an emulator out there for the new blackberry OS. (I cant seem to find one)

I keep reading that it can support Android apps. So an emulator would be great, so that I can give it a try.

(I dont have the new Blackberry to try it on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Blackberry Tablet OS -Calling all app for the blackberry Tablet OS](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/) link . You can download the Tablet emulator which runs QNX. The site provides link to the android runtime as well. The emulator for QNX phones hasnt been launched yet

Check [BlackBerry Packager for Android Apps](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/) if you would like to package your Android application to run on the BlackBerry PlayBook

Comment: Id been looking there, but was unable to find it. With your confirmation it was there, and lots more hunting, I have it :) Thanks.

Comment: glad i was of help. Enjoy. I am yet to start playing with the qnx emulator. :-) i hope you have lots of fun